# create-react-app build service-worker.js and manifest.json not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, static, http-status-code-404

I have created an app with create-react-app. I have built it and I have written a simple express app for serving the react built app.

I have some problems with the static files and the files which are in the root folder of express app, (e.g. manifest.json, service-worker.js). Now I get 404 on both these files. 
How can I treat this files in express? They must be in the static folder? I have to modify the react app? 
I went to see the file generated by the react build, in which the file 'service-worker.js' is imported and the string starts with '/' (that is '/service-worker.js')

(I have not touch the files for the pwa since I created the project)

[Here there's my root folder of my express app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWg0i.png)

I have only added the project.json and the index.js (and obviously the node_modules), the other files are those from the react build.

Here my express app:

```
const compression = require('compression');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/sketches', express.static('sketches'));
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  
app.use(compression());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'))

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('server listening!'))
```

Adding this line of code I get the service-worker.js but I can't get the files in the sketches folder.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem i resolved it by following these steps.

**warning:** i am new to these technologies and i don't know much about web security. this maybe not the best way of doing it.

i get it work using ejs template engine and express but it should work in your case as well.

1) create-react-app

2) yarn build

3) copy static folder into public

4) copy service-worker.js inside static folder also

[image]

5) go inside main Ctrl + f

6) type /service-worker.js in search hit Enter

7) you will see somthing like that `var e="/service-worker.js";`

8) change into `var e="/static/service-worker.js`

9) finally open service-worker.js change /index.html to /

```
precacheConfig=[["/","d6be891ca003070326267be1d2185407"]
```